# How should I use nested attributes with simple_form, Rails 4, and has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to use `simple_form` to create an object and one of its `has_many` associations with Rails 4.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applications
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.allowed_params
      [:over_18]
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    @user.save
    # there is more in here, but I don't think it's relevant
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, application: Application.allowed_params)
  end
end
```

And finally the form itself

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :application do |a| %>
    <%= a.input :over_18, label: 'Are you over 18?', as: :radio_buttons %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Whenever I try to create a new user with this setup I get an error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'application' for User.`

**Question:** What should I change so I can create new users with a nested application?

I've tried changing `f.simple_fields_for :application` to `f.simple_fields_for :applications` but then simple_fields didn't render the form elements.

Comment: Your association is `has_many`(meaning applications is plural `applications`) so use `f.simple_fields_for :applications do |a| ...`

Comment: @vee I've tried that, but then  simple_fields didn't render the form elements associated with an application at all. As in, I only see the user fields (name) and not the application fields (over_18).

Comment: Right so, is the `new` action in your `UsersController` not shown or you don't have it defined. If you have it defined then make sure to build user's application as `@user.applications.build`.

Comment: YES! Thank you! I hadn't realised I needed to change the `new` as well. Perfect :D If you convert your comments to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Please feel free to answer it yourself. I don't want to assume your `UserController#new` method :)

Comment: Updated to show my (incorrect) new method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of changes should fix your issue:

1. Ensure `@user` object has an `application` instance built before the form is rendered.
2. Ensure you use `form_builder.simple_fields_for :applications`, i.e. plural `applications` as your association is `has_many`.

Changes to your Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.applications.build
  end
end
```

Changes to your view:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :applications do |a| %>
  <%= a.input :over_18, label: 'Are you over 18?', as: :radio_buttons %>
<% end %>
```